# magento 2 custom option price don't want to show?

Tags: magento2, cart, custom

Magento 2 **don't want** to show the **custom option price** in the **cart page**, **customer dashboard** and **admin end**.

Please suggest me thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nagaraju, I Think its new feature in default magento217.